# How to show connected user online using ratchet?

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket, ratchet

Can you please tell me how to show connected user online using ratchet? I mean I want to send some kind of `userid` to the server and broadcast this id to all other connected users showing that this `userid` is online.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to be able to identify those users and have their IDs, then write a simple class that will always listen on a given WebSocket for any user changes (users connected, disconnected).

Make sure to store a list of currently connected users in some sort of storage and remove then if they disconnect.

After a user logs in, connect etc. you have to send a message about this fact to the WebSocket and in your WebSocket `onMessage` function handle that event (add userId to the list of connected users or remove it if disconnected).

All you need is here: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: i have implemented push notification using ratchet but i also want to show connected user online can give some kind of refrence or some kind of example bcause iam stuck at this point need some help.

Comment: Are you currently able to see how many users are connected using your push notifications (via listening to the WebSocket changes) ?

Comment: yes i can see their ip address and session id but i have to pass some kind of id so that i can identify which user s online

Comment: But you don't have them in some sort of database or something ? You have to have a identifiable users. If not then maybe identify them by IP address and some more unique data they provide ?

Comment: bt how can i identify user by ip because user can access the application from anywhere.and yes i have user id in my db and they have a unique id